# Microsoft Diagnostic Tool via C# remotely

Tags: c#, powershell, command-line, wmi, remote-access

I need an efficient way to execute the Microsoft Diagnostic Tool Troubleshooting Pack via C# on a remote machine.

The criteria for the Troubleshooter is:

- Run elevated (admin).
- Run silent.
- Run unattended.

I have found a few ways to do it via Powershell, however without successfully getting it to work.

If run with Powershell I need it to run with credentials from the user running the C# application, or at least being prompted for credentials.

I have managed to run the troubleshooter via `msdt.exe` and cmd through WMI. However, it does not complete and all I see is the process running in task manager.

The Troubleshooter pack I am trying to execute is AERO.

The target operating system is Windows 7, and it is on a domain network.

Comment: Sounds dangerous! But regardless, the http://superuser.com/ might serve you better?

Comment: I believe this is not dangerous due to the fact everything Troubleshooter can do is possible with WMI.
Reason for me not wanting to rewrite everything in WMI is that it drastically slows down the troubleshooting time :(

Comment: Just a guess, if you are the administrator of those machines, you could execute it with your account on all machines. Or those connected via AD.

Comment: That is the idea, yes.

Comment: Running the proces AND elevated AND under the user's credentials (if not an administrator on the machine) is not possible afaik.

Comment: @bluuf I beleive you misunderstood.
The process needs to be run elevated with the `executers` credentials.
It is a Domain Network and the users that are going to execute this will all have admin privileges on all machines via Active Directory.

Comment: All of this is possible *and* secure *and* available OOTB *and* configurable using security policies in a domain, in the form of WinRM (Windows Remote Management). Which does make this better suited to superuser.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a task in Task Scheduler on the remote machine, specifying the executable with parameters, and you can specify both credentials and "Run with highest privileges (elevated)" flag. You can use the Powershell script that launches Aero troubleshooting pack as an unattended task with log collection. Then, you allow manual starting of this task, and then, once the need arises, you can execute a start of a scheduled task via `schtasks.exe /run`. This way the unattendedness is achieved via Powershell script [like here (Windows 7 Resource Kit book)](https://books.google.ru/books?id=Q5xCAwAAQBAJ&pg=PT2208&lpg=PT2208&dq=troubleshooter%20pack%20aero&source=bl&ots=Hu-SkPgqep&sig=1LBsJsTp-canBsNPx0GnMJRMHGo&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0CDIQ6AEwCWoVChMIgeKpzbfVxwIVAXxyCh3R_gbM), credentials and elevated run are provided by Task Scheduler engine. The script in question is as follows:

```
Import-Module TroubleshootingPack
$aero=Get-TroubleshootingPack $env:systemroot\diagnostics\system\aero
Invoke-TroubleshootingPack -pack $aero -result "c:\temp" -unattend
```

Comment: Very interesting approach!  
I will try this out first thing tomorrow :)

Comment: This is an interesting approach as it forces the command to be run on the local session, so if there is a user logged on it can prompt them for credentials. You could even throw a couple of message boxes at them first so they know what's up.